# nodejs sending email with wrong body text

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with a javascript file that I am serving through NODE.  It will take in input and then serialize it, and send an email.  The code is:

```
let aws = require('aws-sdk'),
        ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'us-east-1' }),
        makeParams = request => {
            var emailBody = 'dooba dooba';
            console.log(request.body)
            for (var a in request.body) {
                // console.log(a);
                emailBody +=' test'
                console.log(emailBody);
                // emailBody += `${a}: ${request.body.a}<br />`
            }

            return {
                Destination: { /* required */
                    ToAddresses: [
//                      'xxxxx@gmail.com'
                        'xxxxx@gmail.com'
                    ]
                },
                Message: { /* required */
                    Body: { /* required */
                        Html: {
                            Data: emailBody, /* required */
                            Charset: 'UTF-8'
                        },
                        Text: {
                            // Data: emailBody.replace(/<br \/>/, "\r\n"), /* required */
                            Data: emailBody,
                            Charset: 'UTF-8'
                        }
                    },
                    Subject: { /* required */
                        Data: 'New Opportunity Submitted', /* required */
                        Charset: 'UTF-8'
                    }
                },
                Source: 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
                
            }
        },
        send = request => {
            return ses.sendEmail(makeParams(request)).promise();
        };
```

The script works as far as it takes an input and sends out the email, the problem is what it sends to the email.  When I run it through node this is the output:

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.17.6.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let b = require('./app/bindings.js')
undefined
> b.send(b.makeParams({body: {foo:'bar',bar:'baz'}}))
{ foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' }
loopy
loopy
outside: dooba dooba test test
sent
undefined
outside: dooba dooba
Promise { <pending> }
> .exit
```

The text that should be being sent to the email is the variable emailBody.  It should be taking that and then appending to it, the input from `send(b.makeParams()`.  In my code, I verified that the loop was running by logging "loopy" and then logging the final output.

It then should send that, which I see when it logs "send"; however I do not understand why it is going through again but skipping the loop.  This is evidenced by the second "outside" which is after the "sent".  So when I get the email instead of the body text displaying "dooba dooba test test" I get "dooba dooba".

Comment: `send` calls `makeParams` but you are also calling `makeParams` when you call `send()`. I think you just want `b.send({body: {foo:'bar',bar:'baz'}})`

Comment: Maybe the request.body is empty